# Php create table if table exist change the name of the table and create

Tags: php, dynamic, naming

Information :

There are two databases namely:

`db_pup` (containing faculty table which I will discuss below) and
`db_puprecords`

the code below allows old faculty table to be copied from `db_pup` to `db_puprecords` whenever a new csv file is uploaded but the problem is that I need to dynamically change the name of the table to be created in `db_puprecords` every time user uploads a new csv for example `1stsem2015` , `2ndsem2015`, `1stsem2016`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE db_puprecords.1stSEM2015 LIKE db_pup.faculty") or die ("cannot upload csv".mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO db_puprecords.1stSEM2015 SELECT * FROM  db_pup.faculty") or die ("cannot upload csv".mysql_error());

    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE faculty"; //empty the table of its current records

    mysql_query($deleterecords);

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database

    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into faculty(FCode,password,FName,MName,LName,Gender,image_name,BDate,Title,EmpStat,CollegeID,DepartmentID) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]'
                                                        ,'$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";
        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);
    print "Import done";
    //view upload form

}else {

    print "Upload the csv<br />\n";
    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='uploadCSV.php' method='post'>";
    print "CSV to import:<br />\n";
    print "<input size='100' type='file' name='filename'  required ><br />\n";
    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Where does the dynamic table name come from?

Comment: thanks for the reply it can be auto generated using loop but first I have to check if the table exist as it will be the reference where will the loop start

Comment: You can look for the table name in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.